# Half Screen Mirror Image

Tags: editing, davinci-resolve

I’ve been asked to flip a video clip and display it so it plays alongside the original clip as a mirror image.

I’m using DaVinci Resolve 15 and I’ve found how to flip a clip. I’ve also found how to shrink, crop and move it around on top of the original but when shrinking it does it proportionally so it becomes a quater of the screen size.

Is there anyway to make it take up a full half of the screen so they play side by side of the same size and without any of the image being cropped?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking here.  If you play them side by side, either some of the image will be cropped or it will only be 1/4 of the size because of the extra width you need.  It isn't clear what your actual goal is.

Comment: Thank you, this helps to confirm there really isn't a way of doing it without compromising, I was ever hopeful though!

Comment: I mean you can also squash the image but then everything will be badly distorted.

Comment: Wish isn't a great look either! It'll just have to be what it is. :)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on whether or not you care about the image appearing squashed/stretched.

If you don't care, then you can hold the shift key while dragging the corners of the transform tool to unlock the aspect ratio.  You can also do this by clicking the chain link icon between the x and y values of the "Zoom" item in the inspector pane, and then altering the numeric values.

If you care about squashing/stretching, you care about cropping, you care about the image not being too small, **and you have a fixed screen size**, then the answer is no. There's nothing you can do.  It's just the geometry of rectangles, not a limitation of the software.  You have to compromise in one of these areas.  Maybe you crop an equal amount off of each mirrored half, for instance.

But when you say, "take up half the *screen*," many of us make automatic assumptions about the size and shape of the rectangle you're trying to fill.  We assume that you're talking about a television, most likely, or maybe a YouTube video, but almost certainly something with a 16:9 aspect ratio (a width which is 1.7777 of the height).  But DaVinci Resolve will let you arbitrarily decide the dimensions of the movie file you're trying to create.  So, you could just set your timeline resolution to twice the width of your source media.

To do this, in the Project Settings -> Master Settings, set the "Timeline Resolution" dropdown to "Custom" and enter numeric values in the boxes below.  The left field is width, so you'd enter double the source media's width in that field, and keep the other field the same as the original.  If you set it up right from the beginning, when you go to the Deliver tab to export, you shouldn't have to touch the "Resolution" dropdown menu.  If you do find yourself reaching for that menu, chances are you've made a mistake in the Project Settings.

Of course, If you do try to play a double-wide movie on a 16:9 television screen, you're going to run into the same problems you had in the first place.  Most likely, the TV will add black bars to the top and bottom, and scale your image down to smaller than you wanted.  But it could also stretch, or crop, depending on it's default behavior.  However, if your end goal was always a movie file that would play back windowed on a computer, you're golden.  Just don't think too much about how that window fits into the rectangular display of whatever device the viewer uses ;-}

Comment: Oh wow, thank you for the amazing amount of detail in your reply! Really, thank you so much. I think I'm going to have to tell them the options and let them decide what they value more but watching stretched people is no good in my opinion! I realised after posting this that there would have a be a compromise either way but was still hopeful!